# key-chord not working with kmacro

Tags: keyboard-macros, key-chord-mode

When trying to define a macro in emacs and trying to expand key-chord in process its not working - its simply inputs letters instead. I saw explanation of this in key-chord.el but is there any workaround for this? Thx.

Here's explanation from key-chord.el:

`` ;; When recording keyboard macros, the time between keyboard inputs are not
;; recorded. Thus, the key-chord-input-method cannot know for sure if two keys
;; in a macro was a chord or not. The current solution remembers the first key
;; of the chords typed during macro recording, and keys that match those (and
;; are defined as chords) are considered key-chords during macro execution.
;; This knowledge is not saved with `name-last-kbd-macro', so they may
;; execute wrong if they contain pair of keys that match defined chords. ``

Comment: *Show* the problem, and the "explanation of this" that you've seen.

Comment: I added explanation in question. As for Showing the problem, what do you mean under showing?

Comment: I meant that you didn't include an example in your question. The quoted explanation is sufficient detail in this particular case, I think; but the original question just expected people to immediately know what you were talking about. Examples are usually important so that people can try to replicate the issue and report whether they are seeing the same thing.

Comment: well, there's actually no specific scenario - any defined keychord not expanded when defining macro. I could of course show my chord definitions but it will be no matter at all, don't know if this is sufficient detail.

Comment: I think the best solution is to stay simple, by using default keys when you record a key macro, or just call the command by M-x.

Comment: @XahLee yes, this is what I initially did - call save-buffer from M-x, but I'd rather find some workaround as I use keychords pretty heavily(